How to return ordered, unique data in Excel?
Last year, I asked a question on SuperUser about a similar issue. The answer was great and the formula has been working as I expected. Recently, I've been asked to add some additional columns to the list.
My input data now looks like this:



Name
Sex
Total
Event
Team




Taylor
f
268
Event1
Team A


Taylor
f
252
Event 2
Team A


Halle
f
251
Event 1
Team C


Christian
m
410
Event 2
Team D


abc
m
216
Event 3
Team E



What I'm trying to do is return a list of the Top N unique men or women by total, with the name, total, event, and team.
The function that was provided last year looks like this
=LET(
    data, $A$1:$C$15,
    criteria, "f",
    topN, 3,
    filteredData, FILTER(data, INDEX(data, , 2) = criteria),
    uniqueNames, UNIQUE(INDEX(filteredData, , 1)),
    totals, SUMIFS(INDEX(data, , 3), INDEX(data, , 1), uniqueNames, INDEX(data, , 2), criteria),
    maxTotals,MAXIFS(INDEX(data,,3),INDEX(data,,1),uniqueNames,INDEX(data,,2),criteria),
    sortedNames, INDEX(uniqueNames, MATCH(LARGE(totals, SEQUENCE(topN)), totals, 0)),
    sortedTotals, INDEX(maxTotals, MATCH(LARGE(totals, SEQUENCE(topN)), totals, 0)),
    HSTACK(SEQUENCE(topN), sortedNames, sortedTotals)
)

I now need to also include the event, and the team associated with the person, and their total. I've tried to update the function but have been unable to get it to work. I can't figure out how to reference the name and total being returned within the LET() statement. I figure I need to use either INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP with multiple criteria, but I can't figure out how to structure the formula.
Thanks

Please make this question stand-alone without the need to view the previous question. You can still keep the link, but just imagine if the link became broken.

Get Top Unique
=LET(list,A1:E21,top,H1,gender,H2,name_col,1,total_col,3,gender_col,2,
        return_cols,{1;3;4;5},include_headers,1,
    d,DROP(list,1),
    f,FILTER(d,CHOOSECOLS(d,gender_col)=gender),
    s,SORT(f,total_col,-1),
    n,CHOOSECOLS(s,name_col),
    u,CHOOSEROWS(s,XMATCH(UNIQUE(n),n)),
    t,TAKE(u,top),
    h,IF(include_headers,VSTACK(TAKE(list,1),t),t),
    r,CHOOSECOLS(h,return_cols),
    r)


Replace the last r with any other variable to see what it holds.


EDIT

To be able to include a Rank column, you could use:

=LET(list,A1:E21,top,H1,gender,H2,name_col,1,total_col,3,gender_col,2,
        return_cols,{1;3;4;5},include_headers,1,rank_title,"Rank",include_rank,1,
    d,DROP(list,1),
    f,FILTER(d,CHOOSECOLS(d,gender_col)=gender),
    s,SORT(f,total_col,-1),
    n,CHOOSECOLS(s,name_col),
    u,CHOOSEROWS(s,XMATCH(UNIQUE(n),n)),
    t,TAKE(u,top),
    h,IF(include_headers,VSTACK(TAKE(list,1),t),t),
    rh,CHOOSECOLS(h,return_cols),
    r,IF(include_rank,HSTACK(IF(include_headers,
        VSTACK(rank_title,SEQUENCE(top)),SEQUENCE(top)),rh),rh),
    r)


This is great!  Thanks. It's actually a lot simpler than the way it was being done before.

Another take, for fun:
=LAMBDA(data, topN_, crit_1_name, crit_1_val,
    LET(
        header, TAKE(data, 1),
        data, DROP(data, 1),
        data_cols, LAMBDA(name_,
            LET(
                col_indices, XMATCH(name_, header),
                comment, "For SUMIFS(range etc. CHOOSECOLS cannot be used",
                IF(
                    COUNT(col_indices) = 1,
                    INDEX(data, , col_indices),
                    CHOOSECOLS(data, col_indices)
                )
            )
        ),
        name, data_cols("Name"),
        name_totals, HSTACK(
            name,
            SUMIFS(
                data_cols("Total"),
                name, name,
                data_cols(crit_1_name), crit_1_val
            )
        ),
        u_name_totals, TAKE(
            SORT(
                UNIQUE(
                    FILTER(name_totals, data_cols(crit_1_name) = crit_1_val)
                ),
                2,
                -1
            ),
            topN_
        ),
        list_values_for_persons, LAMBDA(persons, col_name,
            MAP(
                persons,
                LAMBDA(person,
                    ARRAYTOTEXT(
                        FILTER(
                            data_cols(col_name),
                            (name = person) *
                                (data_cols(crit_1_name) = crit_1_val)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        u_names, TAKE(u_name_totals, , 1),
        HSTACK(
            u_name_totals,
            list_values_for_persons(u_names, {"Event", "Team", "Total"})
        )
    )
)(A1:E6, topN_, "Sex", "f")


